# FFMPEG is not recording the whole window

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to record a window as illustrated in the figure below. In all cases, the right hand side of the recorded window is cropped. The command I'm giving is

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i title="example.txt - Notepad++" output.mkv
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this problem is much appreciated.

[image: Using FFMPEG to record a window]

Here are some additional info:

- Running Windows 10
- Using ffmpeg-20181215-011c911-win64-static, but I have the same issue using other versions of FFMPEG
- Desktop resolution is 3200x1800 (dpi scaling issue?)

This is what the recorded area looks like in the example above

[image: FFMPEG cropping right hand side of window]

Update 1:

Recording the whole desktop works fine, however, when recording a region using x and y offsets, the region captured is correct, but the region indicated is wrong. I illustrate this in the image below that shows a screen capture of the desktop during recording. The background image is a grid and the taskbar has been hidden.

[image]

The size of the area to capture is specified to 1280x720, but the region indicated is 1600x900. Also, the x offset is specified to 400px, but the region indicted starts at 500px.

The area recorded is correct! The image below shows a screenshot of the recording during playback in vlc, note that the "misplaced" region indicator can be seen

[image]

Update 2:

I noticed that the cursor, the mouse, is not correctly placed when capturing from the desktop, see recording below. Everything looks fine during recording, but at playback the cursor is misplaced.

[image]

The command issued for the recording above was:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 1820 -offset_y 100 -video_size 1280x720 -i desktop output5.mkv
```

Windows 10 / ffmpeg-20181215-011c911-win64-static

Comment: Does specifying desktop with window size give correct results?

Comment: It is possible to capture a section of the desktop using x and y offsets, but there is an issue with the region indicator. I updated the question and show some additional screenshots.

Comment: I also noticed that when recording a section of the screen then the mouse is misplaced. I added a recording to illustrate, see update 2.

Comment: What if your change your scaling does it all go away?  Sounds like some bugs in gdigrab, feel free to file a trac, somebody will get to it in...years, or a patch to fix would be ideal, or offer funding, cheers!

Comment: Based on what I see, dpi scaling isn't carried out if input is a title. Also, ffmpeg's manifest doesn't mark itself as dpi aware.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Having the exact same problem on ubuntu

Comment: No, unfortunately not, last time I checked the problem remained...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments to the question, ffmpeg does not handle different DPI settings in Windows. However I believe there is a solution to the scaling issue mentioned. It is as follows:

1. Go to where *ffmpeg.exe* is installed and open the property window on it,
   [img: ffmpeg property window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x3Zx.png)
2. If you are admin enough then click the "Change settings for all users" button
   [img: all users properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35oob.png)
3. Click the "Change high DPI settings" button
   [img: DPI scaling override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSwwx.png)
4. Tick "Override high DPI scaling behavior. And ensure "Scaling performed by: Automatic" is selected

**Reference:**

https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free/issues/56#issuecomment-306900403

Comment: This solves the problem. I have been looking for a solution to this problem for quite some time, if I could up vote this answer more, I would.

Comment: Accepting the answer is the most I could hope for. Been using SO for years but this is the first time I could actually contribute :)
Your question came up in my searches while I tried to find out why the automation at work was struggling for me to record (me being the only windows user I had to find the answer) I found the answer and came back here happy to help.